# image stitching for more than 2 images

Tags: matlab, image-stitching

I am trying to implement an image stitching algorithm and came across this wonderful code posted on http://code.google.com/p/panorama-provider/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2F%20panorama-provider%20--username%20walkingmu . The problem with this code is that it can do only for 2 images. I tried modifying the code for handling multiple images but when it came to find the correlation between images in the file SURFFEAT.m I got stuck. Any suggestions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Matlab you may be able to modify this code by [http://flagshipbio.com/news/flagship-biosciences-expands-tissue-image-analysis-leadership/](http://www.crisluengo.net/) to add multiple times and display the intermediate results.
http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/blog/index.php/archives/393. The script is [here](http://www.crisluengo.net/wp-content/uploads/bigsur_new.m). You would need the [DIPimage toolbox](http://www.diplib.org) and Matlab. 
This is a great reference, check section 5:
http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70092

Matthew Brown at University of Bath, has a [free demo](http://matthewalunbrown.com/autostitch/autostitch.html) of his Autostitch.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Run the algorithm multiple times?  Stitch images 1 and 2, save, stitch in number 3, save...

Comment: Probably possible, but i would like to show each step at a time. I.e show the matches between each images ( like how they show for 2 images).